# Using GPS on Services

Tags: android, gps

On this code i want to get the gps location every 3 seconds. but when i run this program on my device it tells me that latitude and longitude are both 0 every time. how should i handle this problem?
and what is the looper task ?? it gives me error when i donot use it

```
public class LocationService extends Service  {

final static String TAG = "MyService";
double latitude ;
double Longitude ;
LocationManager lm;
LocationListener ll;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
                    new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                    Looper.prepare();
                    while(true){
                    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
                    ll = new MyLocationListener();

                    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                    0, 0, ll);       
               //when i log here , it gives me wronganswer                          
               Log.d(TAG,Double.toString(latitude));
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        }
                    }
                }.start();
                    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG, "OnDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
}

class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            //when i log here , it gives me correct answer
            double lat = location.getLatitude();
            double lon = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = lat;
            Longitude = lon;
        }
        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        }
 };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you get location from GPS, it can take some time, because GPS module needs to find satellites. So you need to wait couple or few minutes while GPS module find satellites. If WI-FI location provider available you can get location more quick.

Additional info about location providers you can find here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Since Android has

```
GPS_PROVIDER and NETWORK_PROVIDER
```

you can register to both and start fetch events from onLocationChanged(Location location) from two at the same time. So far so good. Now the question do we need two results or we should take the best. As I know GPS_PROVIDER results have better accuracy than NETWORK_PROVIDER.

for example you have location listener:

```
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
       //here you get locations from both providers
    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
};
```

YOu need to do something like that:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,locationListener);
lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,locationListener);
```

but before registering you need to check is these providers available on this device, like that:

```
boolean network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
boolean gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```